# MYSQL Select email from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables with this structure

```
Table 1
E-mail - User - Login
Table 2
Deals - Dealer - Login
```

I would like to do something similar to Select from table 1 the email get the login and echo table 2 deals & dealer

Now i done this but I know is wrong

```
$sql = "SELECT Login,Deals,Dealers FROM users AND deals where Email = '$email' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo " <strong> Balance: </strong> " . $row["Balance"]. " <strong>MT5 Trading Number</strong> " . $row["Login"].  "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";

}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow try to show some code of how you attempted to solve the problem

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this :

```
SELECT t1.Email, t1.Login, t2.Deals, t2.Dealer
FROM users as t1
LEFT JOIN deals as t2 ON t2.Login = t1.Login
WHERE t1.Email = :email
```

1. I select the column of each table using an alias (`t1` and `t2`)
2. I select those row from table users then use a join based on the column `Login`
3. I added a where condition on `Email` as you did it too

Try to use prepare statement (`:email`) and bind the param `$email` to avoid SQL injection

---

EDIT :

Now if you want only the `Email` and `Login` of users that have some `Deals` and `Dealers` in table `deals` : replace the `LEFT JOIN` by `INNER JOIN`

---

Here is some link to understand how `MySQL` join works :

- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins
- [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
select Table2.Login, Deals, Dealer from Table1 inner join Table2 on Table1.Login = Table2.login
where Table1.Email = 'something
```